# При команде php artisan migrate в laravel выдает вот такое

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel, миграция

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view alr
eady exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id`
int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
`email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token`
 varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) d
efault character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

Выдает вот такое,не знаю почему не работает

Comment: Переведите ошибку на русский - поймете.

Comment: Table 'users' already exists

Answer (score -2):

Пишет, таблица 'users' уже существует. 
Вероятно вы писали artisan make:migration users

При выполнении команды, скрипт, помимо файла миграции, создает соответствующую таблицу.